# Alternative to the linear Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> As an alternative to the linear Taylor polynomial, construct a linear
> polynomial q(x), satisfying
>
> $$q(a)=f(a),\quad q(b)=f(b)$$ for given points $a$ and $b$.

To solve this problem I considered linear function $q(x)$ so that it passes through the points  $(a,f(a))$, $(b,f(b))$:

$$q(x)=f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)$$

Is my approach right?

Comment: I don't understand the link with Taylor, but your solution is fine

Comment: Ok thank you. I think the link is both linear polynomials are approximation of the function.

Comment: Next, quadratic with 3 points.

Comment: @martycohen Next, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960763/what-we-get-from-comparing-qx-p-3x-ex-numerically