# What we get from comparing $q(x)$ , $P_3(x)$ , $e^x$ numerically?

Tags: taylor-expansion

> For $f(x)=e^x$, construct a cubic polynomial $q(x)$ for which
>
> $$q(0)=f(0),\quad q(1)=f(1)$$ $$q'(0)=f'(0),\quad q'(1)=f'(1)$$
> Numerically compare it to $e^x$ and the Taylor polynomial $P_3(x)$ of
> the formula
> $P_n(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}f''(a)+\cdots+\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)$ for $0\le x\le 1
> $.

I get $q(x)=(3-e)x^3+(2e-5)x^2+x+1$ and third degree Taylor polynomial of $f(x)=e^x$ at $x_0=0$ is $P_3(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}$. But my question is what is the point of this problem and what we conclude of we compare $P_3(x) $ and $q(x)$ and $e^x$?

For example for $x=\frac12$ I got these results in calculator (I write it up to fifth decimal):

$e^{0.5}=1.64872$

$q(0.5)=1.64435$

$P_3(0.5)=1.64583$

EDIT:
Why $q(x)$ approximate the function precisely like Taylor polynomial do?

Comment: One of the requirements was that $q(1)=f(1)$.  With $q(x)=x^3-2x^2+x+1$ we get $q(1)=1-2+1+1=1$ but $f(1)=e$.

Comment: Oh I made a mistake let me solve the system of equation again and fix the problem.

Comment: @lulu I fixed it.

Comment: I think if you plot [the three functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5Ex%2C+%283-e%29x%5E3%2B%282e-5%29x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%2C+1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2F2%2Bx%5E3%2F6+from+0+to+2) the point becomes clear.

Comment: Note:  I had a typo in the link the first time I posted the prior comment, it should be corrected now.

Comment: @lulu it seems these polynomials are good approximations of $e^x$ at $0\le x\le 1$. but I don't understand why $q(x)$ approximate the function well like the Taylor polynomial

Comment: The Taylor polynomials are only guaranteed to be good approximations near $0$.  By bringing in data near $1$ you can hope to get a decent approximation that works in a broader range.

Comment: Another polynomial to compare is the Chebychev polynomial which will come close to minimizing the maximum error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the opportunity to choose four numerical parameters to write a function that approximates $e^x$ on the unit interval how might you proceed?

One way is to find a cubic with the same value and slope at each end of the interval. Another is to use the first four terms of the power series for the exponential.

The problem asks you to compare these strategies. The picture in the comment from @lulu is a good place to start. The Taylor polynomial will match better at the origin but not as well at $x=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. the problem didn't specifically mentioned the center of Taylor polynomial. do you think I had to consider center $a=0.5$?

Comment: Since $a$ is not specified, you could indeed center the Taylor series anywhere. $a=1/2$ is probably a good candidate.